# for() and mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I use the Paypal IPN. When the user buys articles, I use this code to generate codes they can redeem. However, it's not working:

```
public function clave(){
       $Valores = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
       $ValorTemporal = "";
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        $ValorTemporal .= substr($Valores,rand(0,37),1);

        }
        return $ValorTemporal;
    }

    public function cupon($items){
                $mysqli = $this->connection();
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $items; $i++) {
        $yz= $this->clave();
    $sqli.$i = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ventas (id_venta, id_usuario,id_producto ,used,cupon) VALUES ('$txn_id','$username','$item_name','$used','$yz')");

    }

            return true;
    }
```

`$items` is the number of products
I don't know if I'm using the `for()` statement correctly.

Comment: what is this? `$sqli.$i` also `$txn_id` `$username` `$item_name` `$used` are undefined in you `cupon` function

Comment: $sql is just an idintifier the others are defined globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function cupon($items){
    global $txn_id, $username, $item_name, $used;

    $mysqli = $this->connection();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $items; $i++) {
        $yz = $this->clave();
        $mysqli->query("
            INSERT INTO `ventas` 
                (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `id_producto`, `used`, `cupon`) 
            VALUES 
                ('$txn_id', '$username', '$item_name', '$used', '$yz')
        ");
    }
    return true;
}
```

OR little better

```
public function cupon($items, $txn_id, $username, $item_name, $used){
    $mysqli = $this->connection();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $items; $i++) {
        $yz = $this->clave();
        $mysqli->query("
            INSERT INTO `ventas` 
                (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `id_producto`, `used`, `cupon`) 
            VALUES 
                ('$txn_id', '$username', '$item_name', '$used', '$yz')
        ");
    }
    return true;
}
```